# Deleting a tree structure without leaking memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, tree

I am implementing Monte Carlo tree search and I need to store the game tree, to do this I use the following

```
struct Node {
    Move move;
    double visits = 0;
    double priorProbability = 0;
    double QValueSum = 0;
    double stateValue = 0;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
};

Node *newNode(Move move) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->move = move;
    return temp;
}
```

I will also need to delete nodes at some point. I have written the following to do that

```
void prune(Node* toPrune)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toPrune->children.size(); ++i)
    {
        prune(toPrune->children[i]);
    }
    toPrune->children.clear();
    delete toPrune;
}
```

However I am not sure if this will result in a memory leak.

Am I correct in thinking that this will not cause a memory leak?

Comment: Use `unique_ptr` and all you problems will go away.

Comment: I think your memory is safe if you always call prune, but if you forget that you will have memory-leaks, and if you call twice the program will chrush. with `unique_ptr` you will not have to pay attention to prune

Comment: `toPrune->children.clear();` is unnecessary (but harmless), apart from that you're good.

Comment: Do you really need pointer? Can't you use `std::vector<Node> children;`?

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;`